# How can I build a query to get all the distinct couples (column1, column2) and the count() of each couple.?

Tags: mysql

Now for a bit of detail.

I want to grab all the distinct couples (column1, column2) and the count() of each couple.

for example, for the following table:

```
column1    column2 
a          1
a          1
a          2
b          1
b          2
b          1
```

I want to get

```
column1 column2 count
a       1       2
a       2       1
b       1       2
b       2       1
```

i'm using mysql

Comment: `select column1,column2,count(*) from t group by colum1,column2` guess should do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT column1, column2, count(*) AS "count"
FROM table GROUP BY column1, column2;
```

Comment: This works, but how do I hande it if I have a bunch more columns many of which are used in the where clause?

Comment: @Bogdan Filtering additional columns in the where clause won't matter here. As long as you don't use additional columns in the `SELECT` list that aren't in the `GROUP BY` it'll work as you want.

Comment: I'll need to rethink my huge ass query for that to work but the only other option is to iterate trough it all and count in php so i'd rather just have them delivered by mysql